# Get current LDAP Path dynamically

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

I'm developing a library with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

I want to retrieve all active directory users and it works great. But my problem if I run my program on another domain I have to change this:

```
private static string ldapPath = "LDAP://DC=ic,DC=local";
```

And recompile it with the new data for the new domain.

Is there any way to get `"LDAP://DC=ic,DC=local"` dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done the exact same thing few weeks ago. I used the `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` library, and used the `Domain` and `DomainController` objects to find what you are looking for.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public static class DomainManager
{
    static DomainManager()
    {
        Domain domain = null;
        DomainController domainController = null;
        try
        {
            domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
            DomainName = domain.Name;
            domainController = domain.PdcRoleOwner;
            DomainControllerName = domainController.Name.Split('.')[0];
            ComputerName = Environment.MachineName;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (domain != null)
                domain.Dispose();
            if (domainController != null)
                domainController.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static string DomainControllerName { get; private set; }

    public static string ComputerName { get; private set; }

    public static string DomainName { get; private set; }

    public static string DomainPath
    {
        get
        {
            bool bFirst = true;
            StringBuilder sbReturn = new StringBuilder(200);
            string[] strlstDc = DomainName.Split('.');
            foreach (string strDc in strlstDc)
            {
                if (bFirst)
                {
                    sbReturn.Append("DC=");
                    bFirst = false;
                }
                else
                    sbReturn.Append(",DC=");

                sbReturn.Append(strDc);
            }
            return sbReturn.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string RootPath
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", DomainName, DomainPath);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, You simply call `DomainManager.DomainPath`, everything is initialized once (it avoids resource leaks) or `DomainName` and so on. Or RootPath, which is very useful to initialize the root `DirectoryEntry` for `DirectorySearcher`.

I hope this answers your question and could help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, what you are looking for is the default naming context, that information is held in the RootDSE context which is common to all domains:

```
DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");

string defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value;
```

Comment: @Gnial0id `Is there any way to get "LDAP://DC=ic,DC=local" dynamically?` How does my answer not achieve this? Do you even know what the default naming context is?

Comment: My bad, you are right. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding and the situation. And I deplore the way you deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context - uses the current domain you're connected to
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!