# Implement treeview in asp.net which looks like active directory OUs

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, treeview

For now,I have connected my web application with Active Directory by using Directory Entry object and have filled treeview nodes with hard coded values. I

In future, if someone add new Organizational Unit, I'll have to add this manually again.

Instead of doing this, I want to bind all organizational units on my treeview dynamically.

Please suggest me , how can I achieve this functionality?

Here is my code:

```
PrincipalContext ouContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "10.27.25.164", "OU=Users,OU=SanFransisco,OU=America,DC=server,DC=local", AD.LDAPUser, AD.LDAPPasswoprd);
```

My active directory arborescence looks like this:

```
Server.Local
---America
   ...SanFrancisco
   ...Mexico
      .... Users
---India
   ...Bangalore
       .... Users
   ...Chennai
       .... Users
---China
   ...Shangai
```

I need to implement a function, which has to bind all the values from Active Directory to asp.net treeview control as dynamically.

In my case, my company wants to add new OUs as Japan. My system people will add the new OU on Active directory server. But its not get updated with my application treeview until I'll add the new Organizational unit as manually.

They need this scenario as dynamic one. When any admin will add new OUs on active directory, the application has to automatically retrieve the new added OU on treeview(treeview1).

How can we do this? Please help me to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Acquiring AD OU list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903541/acquiring-ad-ou-list)

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use `DirectoryEntry` object than `PrincipalContext`.

In your case, you could initialize a DirectoryEntry object which correspond to your root OU (server.local) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23388140/922977) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390899/922977).

Then, you could request your AD using a DirectorySearcher like this:
      DirectorySearcher searcher = null;
      SearchResultCollection result = null;

```
try
{
    searcher = new DirectorySearcher(RootEntry, "(objectClass=organizationalunit)", null, SearchScope.Subtree);

    result = searcher.FindAll();

    list.AddRange(from SearchResult res in result
                  select Entry = res.GetDirectoryEntry());
}
finally
{
    if (searcher != null) searcher.Dispose();
    if (result!= null) result.Dispose();
}
```

Once your have your DirectoryEntry list, you can work on their LDAP path to know who's the parent and who's the child, and at the end, build your treeview.

Take care to dispose each entry in your list once you don't need these anymore.

---

#### EDIT

The same question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903541/acquiring-ad-ou-list) !

Comment: I got it by your code but how can I bind this list values on my asp.net treeview(treeview1) control?